# Split results of du command by new line

Tags: sed, sh, du

I have got a list of the top 20 files/folders that are taking the most amount of room on my hard drive. I would like to separate them into `size   path/to/file`. Below is what I have done so far.

I am using: `var=$(du -a -g /folder/ | sort -n -r | head -n 20)`. It returns the following:

```
120    /path/to/file
115    /path/to/another/file
110    /file/path/
```

etc.

I have tried the following code to split it up into single lines.

```
for i in $(echo $var | sed "s/\n/ /g")
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

The result I would like is as follows:

```
120 /path/to/file,
115 /path/to/another/file,
110 /file/path/,
```

etc.

This however is the result I am getting:

```
120, 
/path/to/file,
115, 
/path/to/another/file,
110, 
/file/path/,
```

etc.

Comment: `var=$(cmd... )` is almost always a ticket to trouble. Slightly better is `varArr=( $(cmd ...) )` where what is returned is stored as an array that you can access with either `${varArr[@]}` (for the whole thing), or individually, with `${varArr[1]}` (but starting at `0`). Better still (usually) is `( cmds_that_produce_output | filters | rearrangers | etc ) | while read sz fName ; do printf "%06.2d\t%30s\n" $sz $fName ; done` sort o thing, or even replace `while` loop with an `awk` script. (Search on `printf spec modifier)But, sorry, don't have time to dig in on your specfic problem. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter Unfortunately, that will not work for me, the server I am working on does not seam to support `bash`. only `sh` so I cannot use arrays.

Comment: If you're using `var=$(cmd)` (the `$(...)` part), that is not "real" /bin/sh (from the 80s ;-) ). What do you get from `echo SHELL="$SHELL" ; uname -srv`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter When i run that command, I get `SHELL=/usr/bin/ksh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `awk` will be easier, can be combined with a pipe to the original command:

```
du -a -g /folder/ | sort -n -r | head -n 20 | awk '{ print $1, $2 "," }'
```

If you can not create a single pipe, and have to use $var

```
echo "$var" | awk '{ print $1, $2 "," }'
```